# Go - http.Post method returns 400 Bad Request while http.Get seems to work

Tags: http, post, go

With the following code:

```
//fpCode and fpParams are strings
ingestionBody := strings.NewReader(fpCode+fpParams)
resp, err := http.Post("http://192.168.1.151:8080/ingest?", "text/plain", ingestionBody)
```

I'm getting the error message: 
"HTTP/1.1 POST /ingest" - 400 Bad Request

I don't know if I'm not using the Post method right (even when in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984931/google-app-engine-go-http-post-byte/8459198#8459198), they seem to use it in a similar way. Is the only example that I was able to find, unfortunatelly Go documentation lacks of examples), the problem is with the second parameter, which should be something different (but I also tried "text/*") or there is something important that I'm missing.

Comment: Why do your query end with `?` in POST ?

Comment: Do you have server logs ? They might explain why the request wasn't considered valid.

Comment: It was an embarrassing error, I can not say something different. I used it with the GET and thought that for POST worked the same way. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhpas you can try http.PostForm:

```
form := url.Values{}
form.Add("field1", a)
form.Add("field2", b)
http.PostForm("http://192.168.1.151:8080/ingest", form)
```

Comment: Thanks, I already knew PostForm but I thought it didn´t "apply" with my case. Now I think it does and makes things easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a POST you should probably be using a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Ultimately you need to look at the server logs to determine why the request is failing.

You might try [http.PostForm()](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm) instead.

Comment: As I said to Joe, I will go for PostForm, but probably will try using also Post, just for the shake of seeing if it also works. Thanks fo r the suggestion.